# Not getting how to write power mock test cases for below use case

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I am having one java code scenario but not getting how to write power mock test cases for that.

```
Class Test {
ClosableHttpClient c;
}

Class MainTest extends Test{
  // code for httpPost and clientContext object 

   public void login(){
      //code 
      c.execute(httpPost, clientContext);
   }
}
```

The code I have written is calling the execute in real time which I don't want

```
@Test
public void testLogin4() throws Exception{
    MainTest mainTest = PowerMockito.spy(new MainTest());
    Test test = PowerMockito.mock(Test.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Test.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(test);

    CloseableHttpClient client = PowerMockito.mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    HttpPost httpPost = PowerMockito.mock(HttpPost.class);
    HttpClientContext httpClientContext = PowerMockito.mock(HttpClientContext.class);
    CloseableHttpResponse responsetest = PowerMockito.mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
   // PowerMockito.when(httpClient.execute(Mockito.any(HttpPost.class), Mockito.any(HttpClientContext.class))).thenReturn(responsetest);
    mainTest.login();
}
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) not [PowerMock](https://powermock.github.io/). PowerMock should be used to

> enable mocking of static methods, constructors, final classes and methods, private methods, removal of static initializers and more

The examples that you provided do not imply the need for these features.

Using Mockito we can mock the `execute()` call like this:

```java
@Test
public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    // Setup
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
    when(httpClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class), any(HttpClientContext.class))).thenReturn(response);

    MainTest mainTest = new MainTest(httpClient);

    // Execute
    mainTest.login();

    // Assert
    ...
}
```

Note that the example assumes that the constructor of `MainTest` calls the superclass `Test` to instantiate the `CloseableHttpClient` and any other potential instance fields.